# If item not in the lst in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm working on context-free grammars, and I have a function that returns the (terminal values of grammar)

for example:
i have non-terminal function that results in (A B) , from calling say ((A cat) (B happy np) (A B sad))
so technically A and B are non terminals of the grammar. Now I want to be able to get the terminals (cat happy np sad)

```
(define terminals
  (lambda (lsts)
    (cond
     ((null? lsts) lsts)
     ((not(member? (car(car lsts)) (n-terminals lsts)))
      (cons (car(car lsts)) (terminals (car (cdr lsts)))))
     (else (terminals (cdr lsts))))))
```

PS: functionality of n-terminals is described above. 
member? is a boolean function that returns true if an item is a member of the list, false otherwise.
My function returns an empty lst. What am I missing here?

Comment: In your example, why does the non-terminal function return `(A B C D)`? The only non-terminals I see in the input `((A cat) (B happy np) (A B sad))` are A and B. Am I misunderstanding what that function does?

Comment: oops sorry. Yeah you are right. thanks for point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with what you do when you find a terminal-symbol. There are really two separate problems here.

First, you only ever look at the *first* symbol for each rule. Your `lsts` variable is a list of rules; each rule is a list of symbols. So `(car (car lsts))` gets you the first symbol of the first rule.

The second problem is how you recurse after you've found a terminal symbol. Normally, you pass `terminals` a list of lists. However, in the case after you've found a terminal symbol (that is, the one starting with `(member? ...)`), you pass it `(car (cdr lsts))`. We know `lsts` is a list of lists. So `(cdr lsts)` is also a list of lists (or an empty list, of course). This means `(car (cdr lsts))` is just a *normal* list.

I think the simplest way to fix this problem would be to break it up into two functions. First, write a function that gets the terminals from a *single* rule. That is, instead of focusing on the whole input `((A cat) (B happy np) (A B sad))`, focus on one rule at a time like `(B happy np)`. So write a function that, given `(B happy np)`, gives you `(happy np)`. Next, write a function that applies this function on every rule in `lsts` and combines all the output. (You might find the `append` function useful here.)

Writing it in two separate functions should make the problem easier to consider. The resulting code will also be simpler and easier to read, which is a bonus.

Also, an unrelated matter of style: you can (and should) write

```
(define foo
  (lambda (args) ...))
```

as

```
(define (foo args)
  ...)
```

These two expressions have the same meaning, but the second one is easier to read and used more often.

EDIT: As I said in the comment, I would calculate the list of non-terminals first and use that for the function that does one line at a time. You can make this simple to use by nesting your two functions and taking advantage of Scheme's lexical scoping:

```
(define (terminals rules)
  (let ((non-terminals (n-terminals rules)))
    (define (helper rule) ; this takes a rule and returns all its terminal symbols
       ... ; you can use non-terminals in here
    )
    ; now here you have to call helper on every rule and combine the results
  ))
```

Another option would be to break it out into two functions that aren't nested and pass in a list of the non-terminal symbols:

```
(define (terminals-from-rule rule non-terminals)
  ... ; implement, using non-terminals as the list of non-terminal symbols
)
(define (terminals rules)
  ... ; here you need to calculate the list of non-terminals and pass
      ; it into each call to terminals-from-rule along with the rule.
)
```

Comment: but what if my non-terms only works of lists of lists as it input?

Comment: In that case, I would just calculate the non-terminal symbols once and put them in a variable. I'll edit that into my answer because there isn't enough room for code in a comment.